# How to set a default value in selectize.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selectize.js

I'm trying to find a way to set a default value in selectize.js.

I know that in jQuery you can use:

```
$(".country").val("US");
```

But this doesnt work with Selectize. I already read the API documentation and I tried using:

```
$(".country").selectize().setValue("US");
```

But it doesnt work either.

I'm a newbie so I'm probably missing something here but can't figure out what. Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md), API functions are called on the selectize property that the selectize() call adds to the original select or input element; this property points to the underlying selectize instance.

Since it's a property of the element, you use the [0] syntax to the element from jQuery:

```
// initialize the selectize control
var $select = $('.country').selectize();

$select[0].selectize.setValue("US");
```

Comment: if i am adding new option using 
 var $select =$('#dept').selectize({
            create: true,
            sortField: 'text'
        });
then how to set its value.

Answer (score 2):

maybe items can be used..

```
$('select').selectize({
items : [""], // initializing selected value to nothing
plugins: ['remove_button','restore_on_backspace']
});
```